# Cannot get position from Network

Tags: android, networking, location

I'm trying to get the location based on network. I've declared in the manifest

I've registered the listener and requested location updates :

```
 locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0,  listener);
```

The problem is that I don't receive any location updates in listener's  onLocationChanged()
 This only happens for devices with API level 8 and above Samsung Galaxy S , Google Nexus One
for pre 2.2 devices (e.g Htc Desire) works fine.

after  requesting updates from network provider I've checked if  NETWORK_PROVIDER is enabled:

```
 Criteria criteria =new Criteria();

 criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);

 Log.d(TAG,"best app provider:"+locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true));

 Log.d(TAG,"is network enabled:"+locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER));
```

and returned: best app provider:network 
              is network enabled:true

so everything seems to be fine except no position is received by the listener.

can anyone give me hint if something changed in the api? do I have to set up something else?

Comment: Have you tried getting the last known position, forget the exact API call.

Comment: yes , I've done that . It's null . I have to mention that in order to test this coarse location I disable gps but I leave "use wireless networks" enabled; this is just to make sure the network position is retrieved.